# Delete original file after using carrierwave gem to upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using carrierwave to upload and process a file. After the process is done I want to be able to delete the original file. I put

```
after :store, :unlink_original

def unlink_original(file)
  return unless delete_original_file
  file.delete if version_name.blank?
end
```

in my uploader. I also added

```
class CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  add_config :delete_original_file
end

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.delete_original_file = true
end
```

to my config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

The original file is still in the directory along with the processed file. How would I go about deleting this file the right way after carrierwave is done with it?

Comment: Have you checked file/directory permissions? Is deletion allowed?

Comment: Yeah, I am using c9.io and deploying to heroku. I am able to delete files in the console manually

Comment: Ah, ok. I believe you use a wrong callback. Must be :store, not :save

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Still nothing tho :(

Comment: Is `unlink_original` gets called at all? Can you debug or put `Rails.logger.debug` inside?

Comment: I added it. Its not getting flipped for some odd reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91142/discussion-between-matthew-slaton-and-the-ancient).